# How do I snap objects to edges in version 2.79?

Tags: snapping

I'm a beginner/newbie.
How do I snap objects to edges in version 2.79?
Thx for help,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

Below the 3D window click on the magnetic icon to activate

[image]

Beside the magnetic icon there are type of snap. Click on it and you can find several type of snap inside it.

[image]